# How could I change the location of a button whenever it is pressed in C#?

Tags: c#

I am currently trying to make a game in C#, and one of the features is a minigame in which you have to press a button which changes location upon click as many times as you can.

How could I randomise the location of it between `(12, 105)` and `(220, 177)`? I'm using Visual Studio 2022.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clicks++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use *WinForms*, you can put it as follow:

```
 static readonly Random s_Random = new Random();

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   clicks++;

   button1.Location = new Point(
     s_Random.Next(12, 220 + 1), // x (left) in [12..220] range
     s_Random.Next(105, 177 + 1) // y (top) in [105..177] range
   ); 
 }
```

Comment: @Emilia979: I see; you want `x` will be in `[12..220]` range, while y be in `[105..177]` range. I've edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to generate random values, you can use the [Random class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-6.0).
   As you can see in the documentation above, in order to get an integer value between a and b, you need to use:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int val = rand.Next(a, b+1);
```

2. In order to move a button, you can modify it's `Left`, and `Top` properies. This applies to WinForms, but WPF has similar properties.

The code below demonstrates both:

```
// Can be kept as a class member:
Random rand = new Random(); 

// Note: change x1,x2,y1,y2 below to control the range for locations.
int x1 = 12;
int x2 = 220;
int y1 = 105;
int y2 = 177;
// Randomize location in the defined range:
int x = rand.Next(x1, x2 + 1);
int y = rand.Next(y1, y2 + 1);
// Move the button:
button1.Left = x;
button1.Top = y;
```